# Ajax auto refresh comment wall

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Alright, so after several days of searching and reading I still can't get this to work so this is kinda my last chance. Keep in mind i'm a rookie with Ajax and JS.

I have a comment wall where you can leave a nice little message to others on the page and it works just fine but now I want to add some ajax so it auto refresh every 10 second and get the latest comments.

The thing is I get the whole website to be displayed inside that div and not the comments.

I have a js document with the following code

```
  (function update() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'index.php',
        success : function(data){
            $('#cmt_wall_container').html(data);
        },
    }).then(function() {
       setTimeout(update, 10000);
    });
})();
```

And my Index.php page include the following

```
<?php include_once 'connect.php'; ?>
<?php 
$cmt_list = "";
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cmt ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
$cmtCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if($cmtCount > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
       $id = $row["id"];
       $comment = $row["comment"];
       $cmt_list .="<div class='post-container'><p class='post-comment'>$comment</p></div>";
}
} else {
    $cmt_list = "leave a comment";
}
?>

<head>stuff..</head>
<body>
    <div id="cmt_wall_container">
        <?php echo $cmt_list; ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

I hope this is clear enough!
Thank you very much in advance, you are really my last hope!!!!!

Comment: You have to store your PHP code that outputs your comments in another file like comments.php. And then in your AJAX request change the url to url: 'comments.php'. And remove the PHP code inside the cmt_wall_container div.

Comment: In this case you could work with GET. For example your url could be index.php?comments. And then in the PHP code in the index,php file you can check if you get the GET param "comments". if(isset($_GET["comments"])) { // only show comments... } else { // show the whole page... }

Comment: fixed my other php issue and tried this but now my div is completly blank..  :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more along these lines...

THE JS SCRIPT:

```
function update() {
    $.post( "index.php", { grab: "comments"}).done(function( data ) {
        $('#cmt_wall_container').html(data);
        setTimeout(update, 10000);
    });
}
```

THE PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php 
    include_once 'connect.php'; 

    $cmt_list = "";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cmt ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
    $cmtCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if($cmtCount > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
           $id = $row["id"];
           $comment = $row["comment"];
           $cmt_list .="<div class='post-container'><p class='post-comment'>$comment</p></div>";
    }
    } else {
        $cmt_list = "leave a comment";
    }
    // Return Results To Ajax And Exit
    if (isset($_POST['grab']) && $_POST['grab']==="comments") {
        echo $cmt_list;
        exit;
    } // Else Load Page As Normal
?>
<head>stuff..</head>
<body>
    <div id="cmt_wall_container">
        <?php echo $cmt_list; ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

By using isset, you can detect if your requesting from ajax and only return the comments else you load the reset of the page as normal.. Its one method / approach.

Note this still applies for $_GET.. just change $_POST to $_GET if you need, but by using the exit option.. You dont need to wrap your whole site in a else statement.. its cleaner

So change your ajax url to index.php?grab=comments and add this below your PHP code.

```
    if (isset($_GET['grab']) && $_GET['grab']==="comments") {
        echo $cmt_list;
        exit;
    }
```

By using this approach, you can also control your comments with options like grab=admin_comments or how ever you would want.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as 8BitProgrammer suggested

```
(function update() {
  $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'index.php?comments=true',
    success : function(data){
      $('#cmt_wall_container').html(data);
    },
  }).then(function() {
    setTimeout(update, 10000);
  });
})();
```

php:

```
<?php include_once 'connect.php'; ?>
<?php 
$cmt_list = "";
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM cmt ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
$cmtCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if($cmtCount > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
       $id = $row["id"];
       $comment = $row["comment"];
       $cmt_list .="<div class='post-container'><p class='post-      comment'>$comment</p></div>";
}
} else {
$cmt_list = "leave a comment";
}

if ($_GET["comments"]):
?>
    <?php echo $cmt_list; ?>
<?php
else :
?>
    <head>stuff..</head>
    <body>
        <div id="cmt_wall_container">
            <?php echo $cmt_list; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
<?php
endif;
?>
```